# I keep getting an address out of range error, and I can't figure out why

Tags: arrays, mips, runtimeexception, mars-simulator

I'm working on an assignment that takes in a command line argument and through parsing it converts it into two "soft" arrays. What I mean is they're not declared as an array in MIPS.

Anyways, what I'm trying to do is take the first array and add the corresponding element in the second array to the same element in the first array, using in place addition. I have no problems reading in the elements and getting the sum of the elements, but whenever I try to place the element back into `$s1`I get an `address out of range` error.

```
# $s0 contains the number of elements per array
# $s1 contains the address of the first array of integers
# $s2 contains the address of the second array of integers

# Your job is to implement array addition in-place.
# When the program ends, the first array should contain
# the the sum of each pair of elements.
#
# E.g. (here the value in $s0 would be 3)
# value of the arrays before:
# [1 2 3] [4 5 6]
# value of the arrays after:
# [5 7 9] [4 5 6]

# YOUR SOLUTION GOES HERE

#Counter at $t2 and $t5
addi $t5, $zero, 0

array1Loop:
beq $t5, $s0, exit
lbu $t4, 0($s1)
lbu $t6, 0($s2)

add $t7, $t4, $t6
move $s4, $t7
move $s1, $s4


li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s4
syscall



addi $s1, $s1, 4 #increases index by 4
addi $s2, $s2, 4 #increases index by 4
addi $s4, $s4, 4

addi $t5, $t5, 1 #increased counter $t5
j array1Loop


exit:
# exit cleanly
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

I'm getting the error from `lbu $t4, 0($s1)`. I'm trying to replace `$s1` with `$s4`, but this keeps causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has some bugs. But, I've checked your loop logic and it is correct.

The `lbu` is wrong. *But*, that would only produce incorrect results and *not* cause a crash.

Normally, register values at program start can *not* be relied upon. So, some code other than what's shown would have to setup `s0, s1, s2` before entering the code you *did* post.

So, if you're getting a crash, that's because these registers are *not* set up correctly upon entry to your code. It is the *other* code you have [that you did *not* post] that is the root cause of the problem.

You mention that you're parsing command line options and creating "soft" arrays. I'm not sure what you mean by that [despite your explanation] because they have to be placed in [accessible] memory somewhere (e.g. a `sbrk` syscall?).

And, I am quite familiar with `mars` [I even hack up its java code]. If you specify command line arguments that are to be passed to the program, this disables the GUI [and the debugger, etc]. So, trying to use `argc` and `argv` can be hard to debug [because you can't use the debugger--sort of a catch 22].

Your code was printing the sum but not actually storing it into the first array as required.

I've created two versions. One that is annotated with bugs. And, a fully cleaned up and working version that has some sample code for setup of the `s*` registers [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]

---

Here's the annotated version:

```
# $s0 contains the number of elements per array
# $s1 contains the address of the first array of integers
# $s2 contains the address of the second array of integers
#
# Your job is to implement array addition in-place.
# When the program ends, the first array should contain
# the the sum of each pair of elements.
#
# E.g. (here the value in $s0 would be 3)
# value of the arrays before:
# [1 2 3] [4 5 6]
# value of the arrays after:
# [5 7 9] [4 5 6]

    # YOUR SOLUTION GOES HERE

    # Counter at $t2 and $t5
    # NOTE: $t2 is unused
    # NOTE: this is used like index variable
    addi    $t5,$zero,0

array1Loop:
    beq     $t5,$s0,exit            # done yet? if so, fly

    # NOTE/BUG: the arrays are integers, so the inst is "lw" and _not_ "lbu"
    lbu     $t4,0($s1)              # fetch from 1st array
    lbu     $t6,0($s2)              # fetch from 2nd array

    add     $t7,$t4,$t6             # sum the array values

    # NOTE/BUG: we're saving the the results in a register but _not_ writing
    # back to the first array
    move    $s4,$t7                 # save the sum
    move    $s1,$s4                 # save the sum

    # print the sum
    # NOTE/BUG: we should output a space to separate the numbers first
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s4
    syscall

    # NOTE: these are _pointers_ and not indexes
    # NOTE/BUG: when adding addresses/pointers, use the unsigned add to
    # prevent possible overflow exceptions
    addi    $s1,$s1,4               # increases index by 4
    addi    $s2,$s2,4               # increases index by 4

    # NOTE/BUG: this is not needed
    addi    $s4,$s4,4               # what???

    # NOTE: this is an index variable
    addi    $t5,$t5,1               # increased counter $t5
    j       array1Loop

exit:
    # exit cleanly
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

---

Here's the cleaned up and working version:

```
# $s0 contains the number of elements per array
# $s1 contains the address of the first array of integers
# $s2 contains the address of the second array of integers
#
# Your job is to implement array addition in-place.
# When the program ends, the first array should contain
# the the sum of each pair of elements.
#
# E.g. (here the value in $s0 would be 3)
# value of the arrays before:
# [1 2 3] [4 5 6]
# value of the arrays after:
# [5 7 9] [4 5 6]

    .globl  main
main:
    li      $s0,7
    la      $s1,arr1
    la      $s2,arr2

    # YOUR SOLUTION GOES HERE

    # registers:
    #   t4 -- value from first array
    #   t5 -- array index
    #   t6 -- value from second array
    #   t7 -- sum of array values
    li      $t5,0

array1Loop:
    beq     $t5,$s0,exit            # done yet? if so, fly

    lw      $t4,0($s1)              # fetch from 1st array
    lw      $t6,0($s2)              # fetch from 2nd array

    add     $t7,$t4,$t6             # sum the array values

    sw      $t7,0($s1)              # store sum back into first array

    # print the sum
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t7
    syscall

    # print a newline
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,newline
    syscall

    addiu   $s1,$s1,4               # advance first array's pointer
    addiu   $s2,$s2,4               # advance second array's pointer

    addi    $t5,$t5,1               # advance array index
    j       array1Loop

exit:
    # exit cleanly
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

    .data
arr1:       .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
arr2:       .word 11,22,33,44,55,66,77
newline:        .asciiz     "\n"
```